# warning tried to load angular twice

Tags: angularjs

I have checked online for the solution but it's not working plz assist,following are my scripts.

```
  This are my scripts
  <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/app.js"></script>


  <script src="js/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   My app.js contains the following                            
   angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'angucomplete-alt'])
```

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
$stateProvider
    .state('signin', {
        url: '/sign-in',
        templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
        controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    })
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/create-account',
        templateUrl: 'templates/create-account.html',
        controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
    })


         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');
```

Comment: well, I don't see that you are including `angular.min.js`. how could you load it twice?

Comment: angular.js is packed into ionic.bundle.js, but I can't see the other reference

Comment: What is in the first app.js?

Comment: <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script> is above the jquery reference. the app.js includes 

    $stateProvider
        .state('signin', {
            url: '/sign-in',
            templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
            controller: 'SignInCtrl'

Comment: Post all includes if you want us to help

Comment: I have updated my code, plz see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by ionic.bundle.js. If you open this file, the header of the file says it clearly that is it a concatenation of a few libs, including angularjs. Check it here:

http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js

Comment: thnks it worked after finally removing <script src="lib/angular.min.js"> and left the ionic.bundle.js. Warning no longer there, really appreciate your help and efforts to all of you guys.

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer as the correct one and approve it, for future references.